# Angular how to custom output path script file in angular.json

Tags: angular

How can to config in file angular.json to output script files like the tree below?

p/s: file aaa.js has been renamed from main.js

/assets/js/aaa.js

Comment: What do you exactly mean? Renaming the output files for the angular app? Or you mean how to include extra javascript files from the `assets/` folder?

Comment: When we run ng build with angular it will generate files 
- index.html
- main.js    -----> I want to rename this file to aaa.js 
- polyfills.js
- runtime.js

Comment: You can't do that from the angular cli; what's your use-case may I ask?

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible by using the Angular CLI only.

While it's not possible to perform this directly you may write a simple buildscript for node and include it into your build pipeline:

Inside your `package.json` you may have something as follows:

```json
{
…
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    …
  }
…
}
```

The scripts section are your build-scripts. You may type commands such as `npm run script-name` and it would run the commands labeled as `script-name`.

In the example I've showcased, if you wrote `npm run build` would build your Angular application and place the outputs inside the `dist/app-name/` folder relative to your working directory.

What you want to perform is essentially renaming the files which can easily be done by using the `mv` command.

You can do that by doing:

```sh
$ mv dist/app-name/main.js dist/app-name/aaaa.js
```

Of course that would rename the file but the app would not work at all. We need to rename the references inside the `index.html` file. That's as simple as updating the `<script src="main.js"></script>` to `<script src="aaaa.js"></script>`

So we can write a simple javascript script which we can use to rename the files and update the references:

#### Create a `rename-files.js`

Note that I haven't tried this and you may need to tweak it to suit your needs.

```js
const fs = require('fs/promises')
const scriptText = '<script src="main.js"><script>'
const updatedScriptText = '<script src="aaaa.js"><script>'
const indexHtmlPath = 'dist/app-name/index.html'
const mainJsPath =  'dist/app-name/main.js'
const newFileJsPath = 'dist/app-name/aaaa.js'

async function main() {
  const indexHtmlContents = await fs.readFile(indexHtmlPath)
  const updatedIndexHtml = indexHtmlContents.replace(scriptText, updatedScriptText)
  // remove outdated index.html file
  await fs.unlink(indexHtmlPath)
  // re-create it with updated references
  await fs.writeFile(indexHtmlPath, updatedIntexHtml)
  // rename main.js into aaaa.js
  await fs.rename(mainJsPath, newFileJsPath)
  
  return 'Done!'
}

main()
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error)
```

#### Now we can add a new script into the script sections

```json
{
…
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "rename-output-files": "node rename-files.js"
    …
  }
…
}
```

#### And create a custom script to build and then rename the files!

```json
{
…
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build-and-rename": "npm run build && npm run rename-output-files",
    "rename-output-files": "node rename-files.js"
    …
  }
…
}
```

And finally just run `npm run build-and-rename` and it should do the trick.

Even though this would work I highly discourage doing it as this can work for small applications but there are too many references left hanging once you start with lazy-loaded modules and it can get really cumbersome to maintain